# Prefixing table names causes discriminator column to be removed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a lookup table that is fairly simple

```
public class LookupType : Entity
{
    public LookupType()
    {
    }

    public LookupType(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    // A few other properties
}
```

And a few classes that inherit from it

```
public class SomeType : LookupType
{
    public SomeType() 
    {
    }

    public SomeType(string value) 
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

I also have the following mapping for the LookupTypes in the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
// Lookup Types
modelBuilder.Entity<LookupType>()
            .Map<SomeType>(m => m.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Some Type"));
```

Now this works fine for what I need it to do. The migration will create the table along with the column `LookupType` as the discriminator.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.LookupTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DisplayOrder = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Value = c.String(),
                    TimeStamp = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
                    LookupType = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

However I need to prefix my table names. So in the `OnModelCreating` method of my context I add the following line

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(entity => entity.ToTable("abc_" + entity.ClrType.Name));
```

The `LookupType` column is now gone when creating the migrations.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.abc_LookupType",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DisplayOrder = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Value = c.String(),
                    TimeStamp = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

I know the prefix configuration is the line that's causing issues because commenting it out and regenerating the migrations will bring the LookupType column back.

The column definitions shouldn't be changing, so why is the discriminator column being removed? Is there any way around this so I can keep the discriminator column and prefix the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't specify any custom mapping details on a Table Per Hierarchy inheritance without Entity Framework switching to Table Per Type.

Easiest fix was just to add `.ToTable("abc_LookupTypes")`

```
// Lookup Types
modelBuilder.Entity<LookupType>()
        .Map<SomeType>(m => m.Requires("LookupType").HasValue("Some Type"))
        .ToTable("abc_LookupTypes");
```

Then Entity Framework switches back to TPH. Redundant with the line above, but it works without having to add the inherited types in the Context file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) Inheritance in OnModelCreating:

```
public class FooDb : DbContext
    {
        public FooDb()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        { }

        public DbSet<BarTypeA> BarTypesA { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BarTypeB> BarTypesB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BarTypeC> BarTypesC { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .Map<LookupType>(m => m.Requires("xyx" + "FooType").HasValue("L"))
            .Map<BarTypeA>(m => m.Requires("xyx" + "LookupType").HasValue("A"))
            .Map<BarTypeB>(m => m.Requires("xyx" + "LookupType").HasValue("B"))
            .Map<BarTypeC>(m => m.Requires("xyx" + "LookupType").HasValue("C"));


        }
    }
```

Object graph looks like this and filling this with data (didn't used seed method):

```
public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Package { get; set; }
        public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class LookupType : Foo
    {
        public LookupType(){}

        public LookupType(string value)
        {
            Description = value;
        }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        // A few other properties
    }

    public class BarTypeA : LookupType
    {
        public BarTypeA() { }
        public BarTypeA(string value) : base(value) { }
    }

    public class BarTypeB : LookupType
    {
        public BarTypeB() { }
        public BarTypeB(string value) : base(value) { }
    }

    public class BarTypeC : LookupType
    {
        public BarTypeC() { }
        public BarTypeC(string value) : base(value) { }
    }
```

console app

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var db = new FooDb())
        {
            List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>(){
                new BarTypeA ("peanutsA"){ DisplayOrder=100,Package="packA"},
                new BarTypeA ("olivesA"){ DisplayOrder = 101,Package="packB" },
                new BarTypeB ("peanutsB"){ DisplayOrder = 200,Package="packC" },
                new BarTypeB ("olivesB"){ DisplayOrder = 201,Package="packD" },
                new BarTypeC ("peanutsC"){ DisplayOrder = 300,Package="packE" },
                new BarTypeC ("olivesC"){ DisplayOrder = 301,Package="packF" }
            };

            db.BarTypesA.Add((BarTypeA)foos[0]);
            db.BarTypesA.Add((BarTypeA)foos[1]);
            db.BarTypesB.Add((BarTypeB)foos[2]);
            db.BarTypesB.Add((BarTypeB)foos[3]);
            db.BarTypesC.Add((BarTypeC)foos[4]);
            db.BarTypesC.Add((BarTypeC)foos[5]);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

The generated table in db :
Id,DisplayOrder,Description,Package,TimeStamp,xyxFooType,xyxLookupType
1  100      NULL    packA   NULL    NULL    A
2  101      NULL    packB   NULL    NULL    A
3  200      NULL    packC   NULL    NULL    B
4  201      NULL    packD   NULL    NULL    B
5  300      NULL    packE   NULL    NULL    C
6  301      NULL    packF   NULL    NULL    C

and finally the add-migrations initialSetup looks like this:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Foos",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DisplayOrder = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Package = c.String(),
                    TimeStamp = c.Binary(),
                    xyxFooType = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    xyxLookupType = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Wish Microsoft could find the resource to thoroughly document and provide samples as EF seems so powerful. Not sure if the above fits your scenario but certainly it generates a useful Discriminator column xyzLookupType. Did have problems with db-migration files-debug/obj caches getting out of sync. Still seeking good documentation/books.
Don't fully understand why Description is not being added to the table, it may be because  I am adding BarTypes and not the root types (may need virtual properties). Also may need to add DbSets for ancestors...